# How to send variable from template to global parameter using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a template as following.

```
<xsl:template name="processTopicKeywords">
    <!-- 07Feb
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="topic">
      <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="topic.title"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]"/>
    </fo:block>  -->
     <xsl:message> + [DEBUG] processTopicKeywords</xsl:message>
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="topic">
      <fo:inline 
        font-family="ArialRegular"
        font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]/node()"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </fo:inline>
     <fo:inline>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]/node()"/>
      </fo:inline>
      <xsl:variable name="keys" select="*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]/node()" />
    </fo:block>  
  </xsl:template>
```

i want call the variable "keys" which collects data and send to global parameter. i tried as following but its not workings

```
<xsl:variable name="keys" select="(processTopicKeywords)/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]/node()/*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]/node()" />
```

Can anyone please help me in this ?

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense at all. Variables don't "send data" to each other. Please describe the input and required output of your transformation, then we can tell you how to go about writing it.

Comment: I am sorry Michael Kay. What i exactly want is
      <xsl:variable name="keys" select="*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]/node()" />

In the above code , what ever data is in keys should be declare as global variable but here it is declared as local variable.
  
"(My task is to show the document properties dynamically (Keywords and Subject))"

Comment: Please don't describe your problem in terms of the code you want to write. Show us your input XML and your output XML.

Comment: How to set document properties (title, author, keywords and Subject) dynamically using XSLT? Can you please give any reference.

Comment: Sure, here's a reference: https://www.amazon.com/XSLT-2-0-XPath-Programmers-Reference/dp/0470192747/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1490216332&sr=1-1&keywords=XSLT+2.0